# Estou a tentar customizar a minha template de bootstrap mas não há mudanças na página

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Estou no visual studio a trabalhar em ASP.NET-MVC e tenho uma template de bootstrap para o meu site. Eu queria adicionar uma imagem de fundo desfocada para a minha página do login.

Eu pus este código no ficheiro css:

```
 bg.wallpaper {
        background-image: url(<<adicionei o URL todo>>\Test1.png);
        filter: blur(8px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Depois fiz `<div class="bg.wallpaper"></div>` na página html.

No entanto não houve qualquer tipo de diferença.

Existe alguma coisa na template que está a impedir que eu faça as mudanças?

Comment: As classes no elemento devem estar separadas e sem ponto: `<div class="bg wallpaper"></div>`. E no CSS faltou o ponto no "bg": `.bg.wallpaper {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `html` não precisamos colocar um `.` nas classes css, isso somente é necessário no arquivo `.css` que indica que você ira estilizar uma classe.

```css
.bg.wallpaper {
        background-image: url('https://marketingcomcafe.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/banco-imagens-gratis.png');
        filter: blur(8px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<div class="bg wallpaper"></div>
```

Comment: Olá @OtavioCapel. Tentei o que o senhor disse e não deu

Comment: upgrade. apareceu uma pequena imagem desfocada, como queria. agora tenho de a colocar como background

Comment: eu editei o codigo acima, isso foi porque eu setei um `width` e `height` na div só para exemplo. a imagem vai ocupar o espaço inteiro de sua `div`.

Comment: eu coloquei, mas não ficou como background, ficou apenas como uma imagem. Pus o div a comecar no inicio do ficheiro e a acabar no final. E como esperado, a imagem aumento e o texto que estava no meio também ficou desfocado, como a imagem. Como faço para por o texto e as caixas de texto à parte da imagem?

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira se o problema da Classe do CSS foi resolvido marque a pergunta como aceita. Se tem uma pergunta diferente eh só abrir uma Nova Pergunta, isso facilita pra vc e para quem vai te responder. Evite fazer novas perguntas nos comentários, principalmente se não tem a ver com o título ou com o que vc perguntou antes.